# Why does my Docker Volume not allow for Auto-Reloading my Flask Application?

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to setup a dev environment in WSL2 to work on a Flask website/project, but I'm running into issues surrounding auto-reloading when I start up my project with docker-compose. Currently, the website runs fine, but if I change any of my templates and reload my browser, that change is not reflected unless I completely shut down the the container and rebuild it. I would also like Flasks normal auto-reloading functionality to work. I tried following other's suggestions for adding a Volume mount to my docker-compose.yml to no avail, here is my current setup:

File Structure:
[image]

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  website:
    build: ./website
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes: 
     - website:/code
volumes: 
  website:
```

Dockerfile (in website):

```
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV FLASK_ENV=development
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install cmake autoconf automake libtool nasm make pkg-config
COPY mozjpeg mozjpeg
RUN cd mozjpeg &&\
    mkdir build && cd build &&\
    cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" ../ &&\
    make install
RUN cd /usr/local/bin &&\
    ln -s /opt/mozjpeg/bin/cjpeg
RUN apt-get install -y pngquant
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code
#RUN pngquant --quality=65-80 test.png
#RUN cjpeg -quality 50 test.jpg
#RUN pwd
#RUN ls
EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the below `docker-compose.yml`, flask is able to achieve live coding/auto reloading docker

#### EDIT-1

This is the folder structure of the sample flask app

```
C:.
|   docker-compose.yml
|   output.doc
|   README.md
|   
\---app
    |   app.py
    |   Dockerfile
    |   requirements.txt
    |   
    \---__pycache__
            app.cpython-36.pyc
```

and the `Dockerfile` is

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y cmake autoconf automake libtool nasm make pkg-config
RUN apt-get install -y pngquant
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

and `docker-compose.yml` file is

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    environment:
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1
      FLASK_APP: ./app.py
    ports: ['5000:5000']
    volumes: ['./app:/app']
```

Comment: What's different from the `docker-compose.yml` file in the question?  Why does it work?  Can you remove some unnecessary options (`container_name:`, `entrypoint:`)?

Comment: Can you please adapt your answer to fit my file structure? I think the issue might be that I have the wrong file paths.

Comment: @user3560875 check for the mounting of the file paths. i have updated/edited my answer also